# What transition-property to use for transform?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm not sure if this is the right way, but I want to spin an element,
and I know `transform: rotate(90deg)` & `transition-property:all` will work, but I don't want to transition `all` of the transformations
.
What `transition-property` should I use, and is there a better way to create a spinning animation?

Comment: check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584138/css3-continous-rotate-animation-just-like-a-loading-sundial

Answer (score 24):

To target `transform`s on `transition-property` you should use:

```
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-ms-transition-property: -ms-transform;
-o-transition-property: -o-transform;
transition-property: transform;
```

Comment: I think IE never head transforms prefixed, no?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not a better way, but alternatively you can use animation keyframes (which IS better if you want to repeat the animation continuously):

```
@keyframes rotateDiv {
   from { transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
   to   { transform: rotateZ(360deg); }
}

div {
   animation-name: rotateDiv;
   animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-timing-function: linear; /* For a steady rate loop */
   animation-delay: 0s;            
   animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* Use actual numbers for limited repeat */
}
```