# Can i use transform as a value of transition-property?

Tags: css, transform, css-transitions, css-animations

Can i use transform as a value of transition-property?

```
transition-property: transform;
```

[W3C transition standard](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transitions/#animatable-css) doesn't list transform as Animatable value.

In fact [W3C transform standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-property) has missing row for Animatable:Yes/No in the table of 7. The ‘transform’ Property.

I am worried this is legal or not.

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831795/what-transition-property-to-use-for-transform)  suggest to use transform as the value of transition-property.

I can get the transform animation using 0% and 100% keyframe but if only 2 states are involved, I would prefer transition instead of animation.

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the exact name for each engine. So for example, for `Safari` and `Chrome`, you should write the following:

```
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
```

Here is the working example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLwNC/1/).
*Note:* I've used the shorthand for `transform` property.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you can, however I'm not too sure about cross-browser compatibility. You can play around with it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition-property). Using the code already provided, when you hover over the red box, it moves.

Comment: @PK I know, but the page is coded so that you can edit the code, change it to the transition-property on the left to transform, and it will update on the right side.

Answer (score -1):

```
selector{
transform: translateX(-100px);
transition:transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

> So from the above example, we see that we can use the "transform"
>   property itself as the value of "transition" property.

*As a result, our translate will happen smoothly instead of the immediate shift of 100px to the left, the shift will be animated.*