# CSS3 & GIF Loading Circle

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS3 Continous Rotate Animation (Just like a loading sundial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584138/css3-continous-rotate-animation-just-like-a-loading-sundial)

I have this simple GIF loading circle. Is it possible something like this can be coded with just CSS3? Any help is much appreciated.

[jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/jxAg9/2/)

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div class="arc-hider"></div>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate { 
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate { 
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) }
}
@-o-keyframes rotate { 
    from { -o-transform: rotate(0deg) }
    to { -o-transform: rotate(180deg) }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotate { 
    from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) }
    to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) }
}
.arc-hider {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    border: 6px solid #36669F;
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    z-index: 5;
    clip: rect(0px 21px 21px 0px);
    -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite 0s;-moz-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite 0s;-o-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite 0s;-ms-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: rotate 2s linear infinite 0s;
}
​
```

Should do the trick

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2FwDm/22/show/) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/2FwDm/22/)