# How to spin an image horizontally with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to spin an image horizontally. Usually we use gifs to show that something is loading, like an AJAX request for example. I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584138/css3-continuous-rotate-animation-just-like-a-loading-sundial) but it shows a vertical rotation. I want an animation like  [this one](http://i109.photobucket.com/albums/n52/briandjjforever/mario/Coin.gif).

How can I do this with CSS and jQuery?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Researching I've found an answer to my question. We need to use the `rotateY` attribute for the `-webkit-transform` CSS property.

```
.imageRotateHorizontal{
    -moz-animation: spinHorizontal .8s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: spinHorizontal .8s infinite linear;    
    -webkit-animation: spinHorizontal .8s infinite linear;
    animation: spinHorizontal .8s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spinHorizontal {
    0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
}

/* Vendor specific keyframes go here */
```

Additionally, we have to define an animation with a reasonable time. For example I'm going to set the animation to 0.8 seconds. It means that our image are going to perform a complete rotation each 0.8 seconds.

I've prepared a jsFiddle showing the complete code width an example: http://jsfiddle.net/AB277/7/

Comment: `-webkit-transform` inside `-moz-keyframes`? Looks like you don't fully understand what you are doing. And where is the standard property?

Comment: You are right, @Pavlo. It was a wrong copy&paste in a hurry morning. Sorry for that and thank you for your comments.

Comment: Thank you, @PabloAnaya for posting this answer and providing jsfiddle!